# get user displayName in firebase cloud function using context

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In my firebase cloud function, I can get the email of each user that makes a call on the client side using:

```
context.auth.token.email
```

Is there a way to obtain the user's display name? I tried `context.auth.token.name` but it still return an undefined property.

Comment: Are you testing it in emulator ?

Answer (score 5):

The `context.auth.token` is an object of type [DecodedToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken) which does not contain user display name. You'll have to use Admin SDK and get user by UID/email.

```
export const functionName = functions.https.onCall(async (data, ctx) => {
  const { uid } = ctx.auth?.token
  const user = await getAuth().getUser(uid)
  console.log(user.displayName)
  // ... 
})
```